# $A^{T}b$ inconsistent system!

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

I am trying to figure out how the calculation on the last image comes to be (question 9, the yellow area). I have calculated the rest without issue. I know that the formula for the last set is $A^{T}A\hat x=A^{T}b$, when I try to perform gauss-jordan elimination I just get an inconsistent system?

Comment: If you perform $A^Tb$ you get the vector you highlighted in yellow. What Is wrong with that? Check your calculations after bacause that system *has* a unique solution ;-)

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 8 & 26 \\ 
8 & 26 & 92 \\ 
26 & 92 & 338
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
8 \\ 
8 \\ 
20
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
616 \\ 
2112 \\ 
7704
\end{bmatrix}$ I must be doing something wrong. Isn't $b$ unknown?

Comment: Why are you multiplying that matrix (which is $A^TA$ by that vector? (That is not something meaningful) ?

Comment: My original problem was trying to calculate the \begin{bmatrix}
C \\ 
D \\ 
E
\end{bmatrix}. I am stuck there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original problem is to find $C, D, E$ that satisfy your original problem

Sadly, this is not possible; so the idea is to find a "close" solution, so that you do not get quite to $b$, but as close as possible

How do you do that though?

Solve the *different* system $A^TAx=A^Tb$
This is solvable, so you can find the $x$ (which in your case is the vector $C,D,E$) which is the best approximation to your original problem.

Once you get to the last line you highlited, you just have to solve the system; take a look at gauss elimination system for example http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Hope it's more clear now!

Comment: All makes sense now, thanks!